# How to fix AWS docker pull

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-ecr

I’m having problems pulling a docker from repository in AWS.

I always have this error:

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for [repository name],
>   repository does not exist or may require ‘docker login’

I did push the image in repository from my local machine with success.
Now on the server I need to pull it from the repository and to run it.
I login to the AWS ubuntu server using SSH command and .pem key.
After that, I use these commands to login and pull:

- `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1`
- `docker pull [Image URI from repository name]`

I can see my image in ECR->Repositories.
The login seems successful, it’s returning the token after i run it.
I’m using git bash on windows to do all these.

When I run docker images, I don't see the image from repository, it should be there only after pull?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see the image when you enter the following command `aws ecr list-images -–repository-name <repository>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the login returns the token are you executing the output? The command should be `$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region eu-central-1)` so it executes the output and then you can run docker pull [image uri]

Comment: That was it, I was not executing the output. I have a script that actually executes the output but something was failing on it and after that I was just running the command, not the output. Seems to work now, thanks.